# Kiel oni diras "meme" en Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

### **Kiel oni diras "meme" en Esperanto?**

Ĉi tio estas meme:
[image]

Comment: Tiu memeo estas stulta, ĉar: DA vindue NO vindauge. La Angla vorto devenas de la Skandinava, kun prasignifo ”vent-okulo”. Vivu la diverseco! (Jes, mi scias ke ĉi tio ne estas respondo al la demando! Pardonu ke mi ne povis resisti! :-)  )

Answer (score 2):

*Memeo* estas la vorto, kiun mi kutime vidas.